# SQL: How to pull particular orders based on order details?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have four tables namely customers, orders, orderDetails and Products.

Customer table

```
cId cName
1   James
2   Adam
3   Ed
```

Order table

```
oId cId
1   1
2   2
3   3
```

OrderDetails table

```
oId odId    pId Quantity
1   1       1   50
1   2       2   45
2   3       2   52
3   4       1   44
```

Products table

```
pId PName
1   Apple
2   Orange
```

I want the list of customers who have never ordered Oranges. I am able to pull records of customers whose order details don't have oranges. But in one of the case, James has ordered both apples and oranges. So, the query should not pull James. I can do this with a larger query. But I want this with a smaller query where something I'm missing.

SQL

```
SELECT c.cId, c.cName, p.PName, od.Quantity FROM customers c
LEFT JOIN orders o ON c.cId = o.cId
LEFT JOIN orderDetails od ON o.oId = od.oId
JOIN products p ON od.pId = p.pId 
WHERE od.pId != 2
```

Comment: The WHERE clause makes the second LEFT JOIN behave as a regular INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this using `not exists`:

```
with has_oranges as (
      select o.*
      from orders o join
           orderlines ol
           on o.oid = ol.oid
      where ol.pid = 2
     )
select c.*
from customers c
where not exists (select 1
                  from has_oranges ho
                  where ho.cid = c.cid
                 );
```

If you want customer information, I don't see what `oid` has to do with anything.

Notes:

- The CTE determines who actually has oranges.
- You don't need the `products` table, because you are using the `pid`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `NOT EXISTS`

```
 SELECT *
 FROM Customers c
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT 1 FROM orders o
       JOIN orderDetails od ON o.oId = od.oId
       JOIN products p ON od.pId = p.pId 
       WHERE p.pName = 'oranges' AND c.cId = o.cId
 )
```

Comment: I am getting an error. I think explicit joins is taking precedence over implicit ones here.

Comment: Your SQL is pulling all records of customers table. (Equivalent to 'Select * from customers')

Comment: @madhukar my query is an equivalent of Gordon Linoff solution that you accepted. You probably do not have customers who ordered 'oranges'. replace `p.pName = 'oranges'` by `ol.pid = 2`, is it working?

Comment: Yes. It is working if I replace the name with Id. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You want all customers that have never ordered oranges. So select all customer IDs that ordered oranges and only show customers that are not in this data set.

```
select * 
from customers c
where cid not in 
(
  select cid
  from orderdetails
  where pid = (select pid from products where pname = 'Orange'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from CustomerTbl where Id in (select t1.Id from CustomerTbl t1
left join OrderTbl t2 on t1.Id = t2.CustomerId
left join OrderDetailTbl t3 on t3.OrderId = t2.Id
left join ProductTbl t4 on t4.Id = t3.ProductId
where t4.Id != 2)
```

This will return Customers who not ordered Oranges.
This is the sqlfiddle link : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c908d/6

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2008 introduced the EXCEPT and INTERSECT keywords for doing this sort of thing. I tend to find that the queries are clearer than when using CTEs.

[Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql)

```
select c.cId
from Customer c
except
select o.cId
from Orders o
join OrderDetail od on o.oId = od.oId
and od.pId = 2

cId
-----------
3
```

You can add the name to the result set by joining to the Customer table in the second half of the query:

```
select c.cId, c.cName
from Customer c
except
select o.cId, c.cName
from Orders o
join OrderDetail od on o.oId = od.oId
join Customer c on c.cId = o.cId
and od.pId = 2

cId         cName
----------- --------------------
3           Ed
```

Answer (score 0):

We have to eliminate users who took orange. So in the below query i have used sub query

```
Select C.Cname,OH.oid,PM.Pname,OD.Quantity from Customers C 
inner join OrderHeader OH ON C.cid=OH.Cid
inner join OrderDetails OD on oh.oid=od.oid
inner join ProductMast PM on PM.pid=OD.pid where OH.oid not in (select oid 
from OrderDetails  where pid = 2)
```